# angular-l10n weird translation with special character

Tags: angular, translate, angular-translate

I am using angular-l10n for translation in my angular app. But it is behaving weirdly when text with special character is passed.

```
<span class="label" l10nTranslate>{{ labelText }}</span>
```

here **labelText** is **1234#$&*() BLAH*** but while showing it shows **1234#1234#$&() BLAH*() BLAH**

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you save your file in `UTF-8` ?

Comment: I have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my index.html

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz ?

Comment: This is happening when text contains `&`